# linux: share directory between different users

Tags: linux, users, directory, share

i need to have this directory, which is created under FTP User1:

/home/User1/public_html/jobs_html

readable by a different FTP user, call them User2  ...

ie, when logged in thru SSH under User2, 'ls -l /home/User1/public_html/jobs_html' needs to display files

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Create a new group, add both of these users to that group, set group rw on the common directory and make that group owner of the directory.

Comment: Allowing user2 access to /home/User1/public_html/jobs_html/ implies giving them access to /home/User1/public_html/ and /home/User1/ which may not be desirable - a better solution might be to move this directory elsewhere and add symbolic links. Also, in addition to setting the group ownership on the shared directory, you should set the setgid bit on the directory too.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting group ownership and group `rw` on the directory, I would also suggest setting the `setgid` bit on the directory so subdirectories created retain the same correct group ownership rather than being owned by the user who created them.

```
# EDIT: Make sure user2 can list files in user1's home dir
chmod o+x /home/user1

# Set ownership
chown -R user1.sharedgroup /path/to/shared
chmod -R g+rw /path/to/shared
chmod g+s /path/to/shared

# Or if subdirectories already exist, setgid for all subdirectories
find /path/to/shared -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
```

Comment: already did that, still when i login under user2 in ssh and go 'ls -l /home/user1/public_html/jobs_html' says 'permission denied' ....

Comment: for the first command, do i do that under root as user1.sharedgroup or root.sharedgroup? the directory belongs to user1 and sharedgroup but still says 'permission denied' for user2

Comment: @sam I think you need to be root to execute the first command.  But you want it owned as `user1.sharedgroup`.  It's likely that `user2` can't get in because he doesn't have execute permissions on `/home/user1` to be able to list the directory contents and enter accessible directories below it.  See edits above...

Comment: the directories /public_ftp are shared on the account  (it's same place as public_html) ... maybe i can somehow copy permissions? tried cp -p didn't work

Comment: @sam please post the `ls -l` of `/home`, `/home/User1` and `/home/User1/public_html`

Comment: user1: drwxr-xr-x  2 user1 group1    630784 Jun  7 12:39 jobs_html/

Comment: user2 just says "permission denied" ...

Comment: for user2: 
/bin/ls: /home/user1/public_html/jobs_html: Permission denied

Comment: @sam Sorry I mean post `ls -l /home` and `ls -l /home/User1` as root or user1.  User2 can't traverse into /home/user1 so we need to check the perms higher up.

Comment: under root from /home directory

Comment: drwx--x--x 19 user1 user1 4096 Jun  2 00:27 user1/

Comment: @sam and what about `ls -l /home/user1`?

Comment: that command will show all files and directories inside /home/user1 ... too much to paste here and sort of private ...

Comment: @sam You needn't post everything listed. Just need to verify that `/home/user1/public_html` is `drwx-rwx-r-x` or similar, and has group ownership. user1 and user2 are both members of the correct group, no?